# Can't find where the segmentation fault is

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been programming for some time now, not that much, but it seems really difficult for me to find where the segmentation fault is, already tried pretty much everything :(. This is for a school project and teachers don't usually help on this things.

Well, here it is, the code:

```
#include "funcoes2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

listaa total_aero = NULL;

void guarda_voo()
{
    listaa t; /* struct list of airports */
    voo novo_voo;
    aeroporto novo_aeroporto1;
    aeroporto novo_aeroporto2;


    scanf("%s %s %s %d:%d %s %f\n", novo_voo.codigo, novo_voo.aero_partida, novo_voo.aero_chegada, &novo_voo.hora_partida, &novo_voo.minuto_partida, novo_voo.hora_chegada, &novo_voo.preco);

    for(t=total_aero; t != NULL; t = t->prox){
        if(!strcmp(t->naero.codigo, novo_voo.aero_partida))
            break;
    }

    if(t == NULL){
        insere_aeroporto(total_aero, novo_aeroporto1); /* adds an airport to the list, I also think that it won't reach here when executing */
        strcpy(total_aero->naero.codigo, novo_voo.aero_partida);
        total_aero->naero.voos_saem++;
        strcpy(total_aero->naero.aero_barato, novo_voo.aero_chegada);
        strcpy(total_aero->naero.aero_tarde, novo_voo.aero_chegada);
        total_aero->naero.preco_barato=novo_voo.preco;
        total_aero->naero.hora_tarde=novo_voo.hora_partida;
        total_aero->naero.minuto_tarde=novo_voo.minuto_partida;
        total_aero->naero.situacao='a';
        total_aero->naero.voos = NULL;
        insere_voo((total_aero->naero).voos, novo_voo);
        }
    else{
        t->naero.voos_saem++;
        if(novo_voo.preco < (t->naero.preco_barato)){
            t->naero.preco_barato=novo_voo.preco;
            strcpy(t->naero.aero_barato, novo_voo.aero_chegada);
        };
        if((t->naero.hora_tarde<novo_voo.hora_partida) || (t->naero.hora_tarde==novo_voo.hora_partida && t->naero.minuto_tarde<novo_voo.minuto_partida)){
            (t->naero.hora_tarde=novo_voo.hora_partida);
            (t->naero.minuto_tarde=novo_voo.minuto_partida);
            strcpy(t->naero.aero_tarde, novo_voo.aero_chegada);
        }
        insere_voo(t->naero.voos, novo_voo);
    }


    for(t=total_aero; t != NULL; t = t->prox){

        if(!strcmp(t->naero.codigo, novo_voo.aero_chegada)){
            t->naero.voos_chegam++;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, if something isn't that clear, tell me, I'll try to explain it

I'll put here the .h file:

```
 typedef struct _st_voo{
char codigo[7];
char aero_partida[4];
char aero_chegada[4];
int hora_partida;
int minuto_partida;
char hora_chegada[6];
float preco;
 }voo;



 struct nodev {
voo nvoo;
struct nodev *prox;
 };
 typedef struct nodev *listav;



 typedef struct _st_aeroporto{
char codigo[4];
int voos_saem;
int voos_chegam;
char aero_barato[4];
char aero_tarde[4];
float preco_barato;
int hora_tarde;
int minuto_tarde;
char situacao;
listav voos;
 }aeroporto;


 struct nodea {
aeroporto naero;
struct nodea *prox;
 };
 typedef struct nodea *listaa;



 void guarda_voo();

 void info_aeroporto();

 void insere_voo(listav x, voo novo_voo);

 void remove_voo(listav x, voo cancelado);

 void insere_aeroporto(listaa x, aeroporto novo_aero);
```

Comment: Can you please correct the formatting? Honestly all off it is not clear ... I suggest that you place a break point and step through the code...

Comment: Have you stepping through your code in a debugger?  What line was it on when the seg-fault occurred?

Comment: I don't know of any debugger so I really don't know which line.

I'll try to do that P.R.

Comment: I'm confused... this is a school project and your teacher/professor won't help you learn it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code entry got all messed up.  Since we can't see all the code or execute it, it's not likely someone will be able to find it.  You have 2 options:

- **Right way**: Learn how to debug your code using gdb: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/
- **Dirty way**: Use printf() to print statements to the console at different parts of your code to help you identify where and when the segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 2):

[Valgrind is your friend.](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, Google is your friend here, but I'll go ahead and say it: its pretty obvious you need a debugger. If you're running this on Linux or a UNIX OS then you'll need to use gdb (http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and in Windows land Visual Studio and its compatriots come with a debugger built in. It should take no time if you're using one of those to find the segmentation fault.

For GDB, invocation samples are available at http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session, and one specifically for segmentation faults is at this link: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have allocated space for your strings before trying to copy into them with strcpy or scanf.

As others mentioned,use the debugger. If you just run within the debugger until it fails, you will be able to look at the traceback to see the calls leading to the failure.

You can use printf statements to display values - the "poor" man's debugger, but you'll find problems faster with a debugger.

Comment: I tried to use that "poor" man's debugger, trying to printf in the beggining of the main.c, but it didn't work. I'll try getting a real debugger then

Comment: @Filipe: Why didn't it work?  At one extreme, you should just place a `printf` after every single statement in your code.  That way, you can determine how far it gets before the seg-fault occurs.

Comment: Uhm I think the problem with printf is that I'm getting my information from a .in file and writing it on a .out file, and for some reason it doesn't write anything. When I tried to run it without writing in .out file it showed my printf. Trying to do it poor man way

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: It was indeed from the strcpy, it says **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001a31d4 in strcpy () from /lib/libc.so.6**, but I allocated memory for that in the insere_aeroporto function